# Flutter tflite always showing the same output

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, dart, machine-learning

I'm using tflite with flutter with [tflite](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite) package. The model I'm using is created by my team member. The model identifies leaf diseases and classifies them into 3 stages.
But I'm always getting the same output every single time as,

`response: [{confidence: 0.9917954802513123, index: 0, label: 0 early blight}]`

only confidence is changing slightly.

image analyzing function,

```
runAnalyze() async {
if (pickedImage != null) {
  try {
    final temp = (await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
      imageMean: 127.5,
      imageStd: 127.5,
      path: pickedImage!.path,
      numResults: 1,
      threshold: .5,
    ));
    print('response: $temp');

    setState(() {
      errorText = temp.toString();
    });
  } on PlatformException catch (err) {
    print('error: $err');
    errorText = err.toString();
  }
}}
```

loading model on main,

```
 void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  print(await Tflite.loadModel(
    model: 'assets/converted_model.tflite',
    labels: 'assets/labels.txt',
  ));
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please change `numResults: 1`, to the number of items from label.txt
i.e, if your label.txt contains 6 diseases then `numResult = 6`